# Snaping circle to rectangle/line

Tags: c#, wpf, geometry

I am trying to implement some kind of snapping functionality in WPF for a circle (which represents my mouse) and it should snap to another object (normally this would be a line or a rectangle).

[image]

Is there a way to do this kind of functionality with WPF without doing all the calculations on my own and if not is there an easy way (library?) to get this kind of information?

Edit: I want to snap the border of the circle to the border of the rectangle/line.

Comment: Isn't programming that stuff is why programmers are programming? `Libraries` are boring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a first step, you should find the point on the rectangle that is the closest to the cursor, and the distance between the two: extending the edges of the rectangle, you partition the plane into 9 regions. Depending on the region where the cursor lies, the searched distance will be the distance to a corner (Euclidean distance formula) or the distance to an edge (difference of abscissas or ordinates).

Subtract the circle radius from this distance. This will tell you if you are close enough for a snap.

When a snap is possible, move the cursor along the line from the current cursor position to the closest point until you hit the corner or edge. You will need to use the parametric equation of the line segment.

The complete discussion requires some care but only involves simple math.

A similar approach is possible to snap to a line segment. Here is a trick: if you rotate the line segment to make it horizontal, you can consider the line segment as a degenerate rectangle and use the same snapping algorithm. Rotate the line segment and the cursor, apply the snapping logics and then counter-rotate the updated cursor.

Answer (score 1):

That kind of functionality only takes a few lines of code to replicate... I doubt that you'll find a 'library' of code to do it for you. The method is as follows:

Keep a collection that contains the 4 `Point`s that form each shape's bounding box. You then need to handle to `MouseMove` event on the `Canvas`, or shape container. In this event, you simply need to ascertain whether the current mouse position is within a certain distance from any of the shape edges... you'll have a little bit more work to do with non-rectangular shapes to calculate their edges, but the principal is the same.

If you detect the presence of a nearby shape, then you simply need to change the value of the nearest dimension to that of the nearby shape... the snap.  That's it... much easier than you think.